# Interactive hover effects of adjacent giraffe graphs not synced when using patchwork

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork, ggiraph

I try to reorder `drv` and `class` in `mpg` data, and then plot the boxplots of `hwy` with those two character variables as `fill` argument in `aes` of the `ggplot`. I use `giraffe` for that. But when I put the graphs together the hover effect not works properly. I want the plots to be synced in a way that hovering mouse in one of them results in same color effect.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggiraph)
library(patchwork)

g1 <- mpg %>%
  mutate(drv = (fct_reorder(drv, hwy))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = hwy, y = drv, fill = drv, data_id = drv)) +
  geom_boxplot_interactive() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')

g2 <- mpg %>%
  mutate(class = (fct_reorder(class , hwy))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = hwy, y = class , fill = drv, data_id = drv)) +
  geom_boxplot_interactive() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
  

girafe(
  ggobj = g1 + plot_spacer() + g2 + plot_layout(widths = c(0.45, 0.1, 0.45)),
  options = list(
    opts_hover(css = ''),
    opts_hover_inv(css = "opacity:0.1;"), 
    opts_sizing(rescale = FALSE)
  ),
  height_svg = 5,
  width_svg = 9
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you reordered `drv` for the first plot, i.e. it is a `factor`. Hence you get a different assignment of the fill colors and more importantly linking the two plots by `drv` will no longer work. The reason is that for a `factor` the numeric representation is stored in the `data_id` column, whereas the `data_id` for the second plot contain the original `character` values. As a consequence there are no matching `data_id`s.

To fix that you could use a helper `drv` column for the first plot to perform the reordering and which could be mapped on `y` while for the `fill` and the `data_id` you use the original `drv` column:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggiraph)
library(patchwork)

g1 <- mpg %>%
  mutate(drv1 = fct_reorder(drv, hwy)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = hwy, y = drv1, fill = drv, data_id = drv)) +
  geom_boxplot_interactive()

g2 <- mpg %>%
  mutate(class = fct_reorder(class, hwy)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = hwy, y = class, fill = drv, data_id = drv)) +
  geom_boxplot_interactive()

p <- g1 + plot_spacer() + g2 +
  plot_layout(widths = c(0.45, 0.1, 0.45)) &
  theme(legend.position = "none")

girafe(
  ggobj = p,
  options = list(
    opts_hover(css = ""),
    opts_hover_inv(css = "opacity:0.1;"),
    opts_sizing(rescale = FALSE)
  ),
  height_svg = 5,
  width_svg = 9
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also tried `data_id = as.factor(drv)` in my `g2` graph and that also worked.

Comment: Yup. But still be aware to use the same order of the factor levels to match the right id's and to get the same assignment of the fill colors. At least for the reprex simply converting via `factor(drv)` in g2 will not work. You could check by dropping `theme(legend.position = "none")` and you will see that in that case the order and the colors for `r` and `f` are switched.

Comment: Very True. That was exactly my rookie mistake. I take back what I said.

Comment: (: But you could of course add `drv = fct_reorder(drv, hwy)` to g2 too. Then it will work.